# Load rss feed from .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

On an aspx page I create a rss feed based on a querystring (`http://localhost:81/Services/MicroBlogs/rss.aspx?cid=34832`)

On another page I want to list the content of various rss feeds using 
*XmlReader* and *SyndicationFeed* but I can't get it to work.

I try to load each feed using the url to the feed.

First I got an 401 unauthorized exception
Added *XmlReaderSettings* and set the credentials using *XmlUrlResolver*

Then i got *DtdProcessing* error and added *DtdProcessing.Parse* to the settings

But now I get invalid chars and html not allowed errors.

How must I do to get the *SyndicateFeed* to read an rss feed that doesn't have "saved" xml-file but an feed that is created in code?

Comment: this is one of those things where [handler files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx) come in handy. Have a look there.

Comment: Maybe you need `DtdProcessing.Ignore`?

Comment: Tried all kind in DtdProccesing but nada

Comment: @Wimbo can't see how handlers will solve it? If I take the outputed xml and paste it directly on the page everyting works but then its a static page and not what I need

Comment: Can't you just use the same datasource that the rss.aspx page uses, without translating through rss-xml?

Comment: @HansKesting Each user has list of saved rss feeds and some are not internal feeds so can't use same.